# Parse anonymous User ID doesn't persist on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using anonymous users with parse but user ID keeps changing every time the app is restarted. I can create a serious of records, tied to a user and see them in backend / the app itself. Then kill the app, restart it and see a new user in Parse backend. Obviously, all records are no longer displayed because this is a "new user".

How can I make anonymous user id persist?

Comment: write IDs to database and query if exists when needed

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly. Parse automatically generates a user ID for my anonymous accounts. The issue is that the ID gets reset if the app is restarted instead of staying the same.

Comment: you mean you want a userID to be generated when an application is installed and tied to that installation? If yes, take a look at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html, Tracking Installations with UUID part

Comment: That's interesting, thanks Alex. My question however is specific to Parse.

Comment: How are you creating the user? Are you checking that the current user is not set already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, if you're using Parse SDK and their anonymous users, you need to check if user is logged in and then run anonymous user initialization only in that case. Otherwise, each time the app is restarted, a new anonymous user is created. Makes sense but wasn't in their docs.

Comment: you can say that again, confusing for no reason. iOS experiences the same behaviour.

Comment: This is a great insight - thanks. Just curious, when you say "check if user is logged in", would something like `if ([PFUser currentUser])` suffice to prevent additional anonymous user creations?

Answer (score 0):

When you 'create' a new user, i think that you are getting an implied 'logon' of that new user.

Note that the [response to the logon](https://parse.com/docs/rest#users-login) includes a session token ( no expiration on token ).

Using 'sharedPreferences' or some other android persistence technique, when you restart the app you can just retrieve the token from your persistence layer and - at least in REST API - just include that token in your headers along with AppId, and REST key and you will get that users data.

If you are using the SDK and not rest api, there may be some other way to get back to a reference for the user.